Why doesn't Excel have the same outcome as Google Sheets when using the RIGHT or LEFT formula?
I have a cell that includes date and time but I want to create a cell with just the date so I tried to use the formula =RIGHT(D2,10). It worked in Google Sheets but not in Excel.
I was expecting the date to reflect in the cell where my formula is but it only works properly in Google Sheets...Excel triggers a decimal like it's trying to divide the numbers 5/23/2024.
